# Get Mac-like symbol shortcuts on Windows

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

So I recently switched from being a life-long Mac user to building my own Windows 10 desktop. There are plenty of things I like but one thing I feel like I'm greatly missing is the ability to easily type many unicode symbol characters by using the option+various keys or option+shift+various keys.

Are there any cool third-party tools I can use that will restore this functionality to me with the same bindings that OS X had? (I'm already using AutoHotKey to get my volume buttons to work with the Apple USB keyboard that I use, maybe AHK is capable of doing what I want here? If that's the case does anybody know of an AHK config with these bindings preset so I don't have to manually figure out and enter all 100+ of them?)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this:

```
; Press Alt+0 to send the degree symbol 
!0:: Send, °
; Press Ctrl+0 to send the symbol Ø
^0:: Send, Ø
; Press Ctrl+r to send the symbol Ԙ
^r:: Send Ԙ
```

?

The AHK-script that contains such a code must be saved in Unicode.

Comment: That is along the lines of what I want. I don't really want to spend the time manually entering every single unicode shortcut that exists, I was hoping somebody had already created an AHK script with these, but if nobody has I guess I could go dedicate an hour or so to the task

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21187/insert-any-special-character-with-a-single-keystroke/ https://thejournal.com/articles/2016/01/26/how-to-create-keyboard-shortcuts-for-special-characters-in-windows-10.aspx

Answer (score 0):

On windows side there are shortcuts to add unicodes using the ALT keys

Insert ASCII or Unicode Latin-based symbols and characters

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-ASCII-or-Unicode-Latin-based-symbols-and-characters-d13f58d3-7bcb-44a7-a4d5-972ee12e50e0

Besides the above link if you search on google "windows unicode shortcuts" you might find other links as well.

Hope this helps.

I am life long Windows Users and recent convert to OS X, i never used these on windows but knew they existed. similarly i have never felt the need to use OS X symbols

Comment: Sorry, I appreciate it, but I know about the "windows"-y way to do this. What I am asking is if I can do things the Mac way on Windows. For instance, in your linked support page, they mention you can type the degree symbol (º) by "holding ALT while typing 0176". On Mac I can type the degree symbol by pressing option+0, which is a lot easier to perform and to remember.

Comment: @Nick you can create your own keyboard layout with [MKLC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/keyboardlayouts.aspx) to type anything you want